# Running tensorboard as python subprocess

Tags: python, tensorboard

I was trying to start tensorboard from a python subprocess and return the url of the service. It works fine when i redirect the output to a file and read from there. But I was trying to read the same from the stream instead of redirecting output to some file. But its not working. Please advice.

```
def run_tensorboard():
    cmd = "tensorboard --logdir retrain_logs --port 0 & "
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
    out = p.communicate()
    print (out[0])

run_tensorboard()
```